# Calculating Range referencing a different column

Tags: vba, excel

```
A.Range(A2 & Lrow).Copy B.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 1)
A.Cells(1,1).Copy B.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
```

This is the code which copies the First heading and its corresponding Column

```
    Sheet A                                  Code Output

  Male   Female                        Male      Mike        
  Mike    Rose                         Female    John   
  John    Kat                                    Bob
  Bob     Lisa                                   Rose 
                                                 Kat
                                                 Lisa
                            Expected output

                Male   Mike                    Male   Mike
                       John                    Male   John
                       Bob             OR      Male   Bob  
                Female Rose                    Female Rose 
                       Kat                     Female Kat
                       Lisa                    Female Lisa
```

Let me explain:  When I use the normal code that I use everytime for copy paste, I get **Male and Female** in **consecutive Rows** which is wrong as **Female** should start from **Rose** . I see that the only problem can be that the range I am using to offset the first column is found by going up, so compiler will go up till 2nd row in first while I want it to go till the last value in column B. Is any of this output possible ?

```
  B.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
```

This is what I need to change I think But need help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to modify this to make it work:

```
male_count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Sheet A").Range("A1:A100"))
female_count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Sheet A").Range("B1:B100"))

Worksheets("Sheet A").Range("A1").Copy
Worksheets("code output").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Worksheets("Sheet A").Range("A2:A" & male_count).Copy
Worksheets("code output").Range("B1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Worksheets("Sheet A").Range("B1").Copy
Worksheets("code output").Range("A" & male_count).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Worksheets("Sheet A").Range("B2:B" & female_count).Copy
Worksheets("code output").Range("B" & male_count).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Comment: What does male_count and female_count have in them

Comment: The number of male and female entries respectively, including the header.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Sub Test()
   Dim wb As Workbook
   Set wb = ThisWorkbook
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Rename Sheet1 to your sheet where source data is
   Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2") 'Rename Sheet2 to your sheet where you want output
   ws1.Activate
   LastRow1 = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Change Column Letter to where you have Male names
   LastRow2 = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Change Column Letter to where you have Femal names
   Set MaleRng = ws1.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(LastRow1, 1))
   Set FemaleRng = ws1.Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(LastRow2, 2))
   i = 1
   For Each Male In MaleRng
    ws2.Cells(i, 1) = "Male"
    ws2.Cells(i, 2) = Male.Value
    i = i + 1
   Next
   ws2.Activate
   i = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   j = i + 1
   For Each Female In FemaleRng
    ws2.Cells(j, 1) = "Female"
    ws2.Cells(j, 2) = Female.Value
    j = j + 1
   Next

   End Sub
```